# How to Run Java program in Background at every specific interval of time?

Tags: java, server, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I had written a simple java code on Raspberry Pi which is sending data from raspberry Pi to server. Now instead of running a program manually I want that program is executed in every 10(any specific time) second automatically in background, so new data is sending to the server after that amount of time. Raspberry Pi is running on Raspbian OS.
Can someone help me out as to how this can be done? Thank you in Advance..

Comment: Isn't this a task for [cron](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md)? (no pun intended)

Comment: How to run a single java program by using cron? or I have to make a jar file of that java program to execute?

Comment: Please provide more inforamtion about the OS you're using etc.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options: run your job periodically from `cron` or something similar or change your application to long running process that will run as a service on your device and will perform its own scheduling. Libraries like Quartz (http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) can be used to do the latter. Slight advantage of a long running job can be smaller penalty when launching the job (initialization and tear-down of JVM).

Comment: I don't know much about cron. How can I use cron for running java file? I have single java proram, so where should I add that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `java.util.Timer` for your application instead `Thread`.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //write your code here
        System.out.print(new Date() + "\n");
    }
}, 0, 1000);
```

I think it's the easiest way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Thread` to execute your code at specific time points.

Example:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                try{
                    //your code
                    Thread.sleep(10*1000);//this is poll interval
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

});
thread.setDaemon(true);
thread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found answer for this.
Using crontab you can execute task at specific interval of time.
For java file you have to make a jar file and then if you want to run after every one minute then the syntax for crontab is

> - - - - - java -jar /path_of_your_jar_file/File_name.jar

But here the problem is your task is repeated every 1 minute. So If you want to make it in 10second then you have to use thread sleep for that.
Code for Thread sleep is

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

timer.schedule(new TimerTask() { 

 @Override
 public void run() {

     method_name();

    }
},0,10000);
```